# Opencv config with two major python (3.7 & 3.8)

Tags: python, opencv, pipenv

For some time I was using opencv (4.5.2 compiled from source) with python 3.8.5 (on Ubuntu 18.04), but for some project, I do need to work with tensorflow, which is not working with my python version. So I installed python3.7 along it (from source), and everything seems to work when starting my pipenv shell, I can work with my python3.7.

But when trying to import cv2, I got the following error:

> ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file:
> ['config-3.7.py', 'config-3.py']

So I believe I should re-compile OpenCV targeting my specific python3.7, but I also want to make it work with my former python3.8. How can I achieve this, targeting the two versions?

Thanks for you time!

Antoine

Comment: why dont you just try with pip install ? Also try with some IDE

Comment: if you want to stick with python, and you have no specific need to build opencv yourself, yes, go with `pip install opencv-python` (or pip3, wherever that distinction is made). don't bother building if you don't have to.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the reply, unfortunately, I need opencv for cpp as well.
Meanwhile, I recompiled Opencv thinking it would detect my two Python version, but nothing got created in /usr/local/lib/python3.7 folder.

I cant see anywhere some info for those files, and no info on CMake arguments in the OpenCv Doc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end I succeeded in having the config files for both python3.7 and 3.8 with opencv built from source doing the following:

I first compiled OpenCv without writing any parameters for pythons. So by default, it detected my Python3.8 and created the config-3.8.py file.

Then, I recompiled OpenCv targeting my Python 3.7 with those arguments:

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-master/modules ../opencv-master -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE='/usr/local/bin/python3.7m' \
-D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR='/usr/local/include/python3.7m' \
-D PYTHON3_LIBRARY='/home/ubuntu/Documents/Libraries/python3.7/Python-3.7.4/libpython3.7m.so' \
-D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS='/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include' \
-D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH='/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages' ..
```

Note that the PYTHON3_LIBRARY has to target the shared library(.so and not .a). I first compiled Python3.7 without the flag --enable-shared, so it was not working.

Right before running cmake (from OpenCv), during the config step, you should end up with those printed information, to be sure you will target the right python: (Here it was for python3.8, but following the above steps will show python3.7)

[image]

Those PYTHON_FLAG and their usages are not in the latest Opencv documentation like the 4.5.2, but only in the previous ones like the 3.2.0:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Then I was able to import cv2 both in 3.7 and 3.8

Answer (score 0):

to solve that issue on Windows, it's pretty similar. The difference is that you have to make sure that you found the proper folder where `pyinstaller` is loading info from, because it's tricky once you have other instances other than the `cv2` container.
In my machine, for example, I could only solve it when I passed the path as

```sh
--path=AppData\Local\pyinstaller\bincache00_py39_64bit\cv2
```

Add that flag at the end of your `pyinstaller` command and everything should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using OpenCV 4.5.5 (the most recent version as of today). I was able to get the same output as DiXcipuli using the following:

```
cmake ../
-DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
-DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON
```

It takes the python interpretter that is currently set as python3 in your machine (say "which python3" on the terminal).